# How can we make a global variable of integer type in Xcode

Tags: xcode, global-variables

How can I declare a global variable in Xcode and its data type should be integer and accessible by every class.

Comment: Did you try a static class with an integer property/public field there?

Comment: I want a pizza. Are you asking a question or stating your specifications for us to write your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some very special cases a truly global variable can simplify things. I don't think you researched the problem exhaustively, but here is my answer anyway, a simple case:

```
// Globals.h
#ifndef Globals_h
#define Globals_h

extern NSInteger globalVariable;

#endif

// main.m 

NSInteger globalVariable;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   globalVariable = <# initial value #>;
    ...
}

// Prefix.pch

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import 
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Globals.h"
#endif
```

Now, you can use `globalVariable` anywhere in your code, you don't even need to include the header file.

**Warning**: things are slightly complex if you need thread safety or a different variable type.

Answer (score -2):

You can use global variable in you AppDelegate :

```
@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
   MyDBManager *myDBManager;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  MyDBManager *myDBManager;

@end

@interface AnyOtherClass :  UITableViewController {
   MyDBManager *myDBManager;
   NSObject *otherVar;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain)   MyDBManager *myDBManager;
@property (nonatomic,retain)   NSObject *otherVar;
@end

//getting the data from "global" myDBManager and putting it into local var of AnyOtherClass
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   //get the myDBManager global Object
   MyAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   myDBManager = mainDelegate.myDBManager;
   }


-  (void)dealloc {
       [otherVar release];
        //[dancesDBManager release]; DO NOT RELEASE THIS SINCE ITS USED AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE!
        [super dealloc];
        }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for help, but there is noo variable with the data type of integer